# Questioned vs asked

Tags: grammar

> The examiner questioned who the first man to fly in space was.

or

> The examiner asked who the first man to fly in space was.

Are both correct? Does using one instead of another affect its meaning in any way?

Comment: You ask a question when you want information. You question people when you want to challenge them.

Answer (score 4):

> Are both correct?

More context would be helpful, but technically both are correct.

*Questioned* and *asked* are both past tense verbs, so switching them does not affect the sentence grammatically.

> Does using one instead of another affect its meaning in any way?

Sort of. I would prefer *asked*. *Asked* is the actual action of *asking* something but *questioned* could mean two things. It could mean something similar to *asked* or questioning something already said or done.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/questioned) supports that *questioned* has two meanings. One meaning is:

> to express doubts about the value or truth of something

so, without a larger context, the reader may interpret *questioned* as "to express doubts" rather than to "ask a question".

Comment: I would add that "questioned" is more likely to be understood as "expressed doubts" than "asked," at least in US English. The two meanings aren't equally common.